# Attach time/date stamp on add_post_meta

Tags: ajax, post-meta

we have an image viewer on our website where admins can tag images thought ajax (new feature on Wordpress 3.0). We are tagging just fine, but we need to filter when they were tagged. We are using normal add_post_meta to update the tagging for the images but I would like to know what's best way to attach time/date on it.

this is our ajax format

```
$imgID = (!empty($_POST['imgID'])) ? (int) $_POST['imgID'] : '';
            $value = (!empty($_POST['value'])) ? trim(stripslashes($_POST['value'])) : '';
            $action = (!empty($_POST['act']) && in_array($_POST['act'], array('add', 'remove'))) ? $_POST['act'] : 'add';
            if (!empty($imgID) && !empty($value))
            {
                if ('remove' == $action)
                    delete_post_meta($imgID, 'image_tag', $value);
                else if ('add' == $action)
                {
                    $ctags = get_post_meta($imgID, 'image_tag');
                    if ((is_array($ctags) && !in_array($value, $ctags)) || !is_array($ctags) || !$ctags)
                        add_post_meta($imgID, 'image_tag', $value);
                }
            }

            exit;
```

My first thought is to create new db table. but if there is something easier that I am missing on WP it would be awesome to know.

thanks in advance